# PropertyResourceBundle conflict with ListResourceBundle

Tags: java, localization

When trying to load a TestResourceBundle.properties file in Java 8 using the following code:

```
ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestResourceBundle");
```

I realized that if there exist in classpath a ListResourceBundle class with the same name (TestResourceBundle.class) as the following :

```
public class TestResourceBundle extends ListResourceBundle {

    public Object[][] getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    private Object[][] contents = {
            { "Test", "Value2" }
    };
}
```

the ListResourceBundle class it has always higher priority than the property file and finally the ListResourceBundle class is loaded.

Is this a standard behavior?

What should I do if I want to load a property file resource bundle and I don't know if there exist in classpath a ListResourceBundle with the same name?

How can I assure that the property file is always loaded and not a resource bundle class file with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ResourceBundle.Control class there is a FORMAT_DEFAULT list that always give higher priority to class resource bundles than property files:

```
 public static final List<String> FORMAT_DEFAULT
            = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("java.class",
                                                         "java.properties"));
```

We can alter the priority ordering overriding the getFormats() method of ResourceBundle.Control class as in the following code:

```
 ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestResourceBundle", new ResourceBundle.Control() {

                @Override
                public List<String> getFormats(String baseName) {

                    if (baseName == null) {
                        throw new NullPointerException();
                    }

                    return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("java.properties", "java.class"));
                }

            });
```